# how to show a calendar in dayview

Tags: android, calendar

i have searched a lot to find an example with a calendar ui showing a dayview, so you are able to see a day with its events.

If I understand things right even in android 4.0.3 there is no calendarview which is able to show day views (only monthview).

So I have to use a gridview, don't I? 
Has anyone an example or tutorial how to do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing, and could find no good options, so I created the [yadview](https://code.google.com/p/yadview/%20yadview) project (https://code.google.com/p/yadview). yadview is a fork of the DayView schedule in the AOSP Calendar app, but has been reworked significantly to allow for integration into your application.

Sample screenshot of this View in an activity:
[image]

Comment: Thak you very much for your help!

Comment: How do I limit the number of pages.I want to show daily events on a page for the past seven days.How do I limit that using YadView?The pages keep swiping infinitely.Please help.